# Angular 2 focus doesn't work if I don't use timeout

Tags: angular

As you can see i'm using setTimeout if i'm planning to focus my input.
If i remove setTimeout focus doesn't work.

```
  <div [hidden]="searchInputHidden">
        <input (blur)="hideInput()" #term (keyup)="search(term.value)" type="text" class="inp_top" name="product_name" id="product_name" />
  </div>  


private showSearchInput(term) {
    this.searchInputHidden = false;
    setTimeout(function(){
      term.focus();
    }, 100);
  }
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The timeout is required because you can't `focus()` an element that is still hidden.  Until Angular change detection has a chance to run (which will be after method `showSearchInput()` finishes executing), the `hidden` property in the DOM will not be updated, even though you set `searchInputHidden` to `false` in your method.

A `setTimeout()` with a value of 0 (or no value, which defaults to 0) should work.  You just need to set the focus after Angular gets a chance to update the `hidden` property value.

---

Note that after the `setTimeout()` callback function finishes executing, change detection will run again (because Angular monkey-patches all `setTimeout()` calls that are made in the Angular zone).  Since the only thing we are changing in our asynchronous callback function is the focus, we can be more efficient and run our callback function outside the Angular zone, to avoid the additional change detection cycle:

```
private showSearchInput(term) {
  this.searchInputHidden = false;
  this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => { 
    setTimeout(() => term.focus());
  });
}
```

Note that you'll have to inject NgZone into your constructor for the above code to work:

```
export class YourComponent {
   constructor(private _ngZone: NgZone) {}
```

Answer (score -2):

Probably you could try something like this:

```
<div class="row col-md-12" [hidden]="messagehide">
{{_result.msgDesc}}
</div>
`this.messagehide=false;
 this.messagealert();   
 messagealert(){
 setTimeout(function() {
 this.messagehide=true;          
 },3000);
 }`

My settimeout function also didn't work . let me know.
```