# Can't add element to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In component i have some snippet of code

```
  isLoaded($event) {
    console.log($event);
    this.visible = $event;
    console.log(this.visible);
    this.onClick();
  }

  onClick() {
    this.listImage = this.imageService.getImage();
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', this.listImage[0],
      '" title="', '"/>'
    ].join('');
    document.getElementById('previewImg').insertBefore(span, null);
  }
```

In html code I have

```
<div *ngIf="visible">
<div id='previewImg' class="img_content"></div>
```

$event return true <=> visible = true, but i have error

```
 Cannot read property 'insertBefore' of null
```

without *ngIf site render fine.

Why is this happening?

Comment: That error message suggests that `document.getElementById('previewImg')` is returning null (i.e. it does not match an exiting DOM node at runtime).

Comment: @Terry why when i delete ngIf matching element is found?

Comment: Maybe because the expression `visible` evaluates to false-y, so that `ngIf` does not render the element. Check what `visible` is giving you in angular.

Comment: @Terry In html i use string interpolation {{visible}} and is true

Comment: Then you have a race condition: even when `visible` evaluates to true, the DOM has not been updated/rendered yet and `this.onClick()` has already been fired. Use `setTimeout(..., 0)` to move the insertBefore statement to the end of the call stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355768/how-to-check-whether-ngif-has-taken-effect

Comment: @Terry I use setTimeout(document.getElementById('previewImg').insertBefore(span, null), 0); but don't help.

Comment: Uhhhh, you have to wrap that in a function call, i.e. `setTimeout(function() { ... }, 0)` please check the link I gave you.

Comment: @Terry Thanks for attention and help it's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, your issue arises because of a **race condition**: when the `visible` property resolves to a truthy value, the `ngIf` directive will cause the nested DOM node to render. However, this rendering is not completed when `this.onClick()` is called, meaning that the DOM nodes within in will return `null` when queried.

In other words, your `document.getElementById('previewImg')` will return `null`, and this is the source of the error.

To circumvent this, you will have to ensure that the selector is executed at the end of the call stack: this can simply be done by using `window.setTimeout(fn, 0)`, e.g.:

```
onClick() {

    // Other logic can happen since they do not depend on the updated DOM
    this.listImage = this.imageService.getImage();
    let span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', this.listImage[0],'" title="', '"/>'].join('');

    // Query at end of callstack
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('previewImg').insertBefore(span, null);
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Or add (load) event on img and put inserBefore() inside?

Comment: @Vega This has nothing to do with the load state of the reference image.

Comment: Ok, this is question question. I thought the issue here was that the image is loaded after the new DOM element is added. Putting the addition in (load) would run it after the image is loaded. So what is wrong ? (I don't pretend I am right!)

Comment: @Vega (1) It's just unnecessary logic. Why use the overhead of an image loading checker when you can simply push the `insertBefore()` statement to end of call stack? (2) If you toggle the same images on and off, it is only loaded once and will not re-fire again

Comment: I went back to the question and saw it... Thank you