# Angular 4 Run Code After *NgIf Complete

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm developing an application where I need to run some code after *ngIf has completely finished removing a component from the DOM. Specifically, I need to resize a google map, but only once the component in question is completely removed from the DOM. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you flip the switch to false just use setTimeout and run resize code there. For more information, check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355768/how-to-check-whether-ngif-has-taken-effect).

```
this.show = false;
setTimeout(() => {
     this.resizeSomething();
})
```