# How to update the DOM before change event is done?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I've created a file input to open a video. And I'd like to display that video input at the condition that my_variable exists. This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<input type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event)" accept="video/mp4">
<div *ngIf="my_variable">
  <video id="video" width="200" height="200" src="{{ my_variable.path }}">
  </video>
</div>
```

The (change) event is called whenever the user chooses a video. And my function *handleFileInput* is supposed to update my_variable like this:

```
handleFileInput(event: any) {
    this.my_variable = event.target.files.item(0);
    this.video = document.getElementById('video') as HTMLInputElement;
    // do other stuff that requires this.video variable
}
```

My problem is that the ***this.video*** variable is `null`. Actually, since the change event is not finished yet, the `ng if` condition in the DOM does not update the view, and then, my video input is never created. Hence the fact that ***this.video*** is `null` at this point. But I don't know how to solve this issue.

I didn't find anything on Stack Overflow, I tried to set a timeout when doing a `document.getElementById('video')`. For example:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.video = document.getElementById('video') as HTMLInputElement;
    // do other stuff that requires this.video variable
      }, 1000);
```

It actually worked, but I wish I could find a clearer solution.
Could you please help me ? 
Thank you

Comment: setTimeout should work. Can you update the question with how you used setTimeout.

Comment: I finally changed the way I called the setTimeout and it worked, but I have to wait 1000ms to get the view updated, which is not really smooth.

Comment: I don't think you have to wait for a second, replace 1000 with 0 and check if that works.

Comment: That's working indeed, thank you for your help !!

Comment: see the accepted answer for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355768/how-to-check-whether-ngif-has-taken-effect), you'll understand the reason for using setTimeout.

Comment: ok I understand it better now, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Having the video tag in the HTML DOM and toggling it with a variable using the ngIf, what you are doing is that you are creating a cylic dependency because of which **this.video** is null since it is waiting for the change event handler to complete it's work.What you need to do, that you add the video tag dynamically

```
<input type="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event)" accept="video/mp4">
<div #videoTagContainer></div>
```

```
@ViewChild('videoTagContainer') public videoTagContainer: ElementRef;


handleFileInput(event: any) {
    this.my_variable = event.target.files.item(0);
    let parentElement = this.videoTagContainer.nativeElement;

    if(parentElement.firstChild) 
        parentElement.removeChild(parentElement.firstChild);

    let videoElement = document.createElement('video') as HTMLInputElement;
    videoElement.id = 'video';
    videoElement.width = '200px';
    videoElement.height = '200px';
    videoElement.src = this.my_variable.path;

    parentElement.appendChild(videElement);
    // do other stuff that requires this.video variable
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I just heard that using id in compoments were not recommended, instead it'd be better to use the @viewChild annotation, but I assume your solution is not possible with this annotation right ?

Comment: yes you can use @ViewChild annotation with my approach. Instead of getting the parentElement via getElementById, get it via the templateReference variable.

Comment: I have updated my answer to use ViewChild. Can you please upvote my answer if you find it useful. Thanks, I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

dont use *ngIf

```
<div [style.display]="my_variable ? 'none' : 'block'">
  <video ....>
  </video>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not use **id** in a component. Use ViewChild annotation instance of id

Comment: Hi thank you for your help but I still have an error in my console when hiding the div because I use my_variable as a path to my video... (the 'src' attribute)

Comment: Is using id in a component not recommended ?

Comment: @marehihd - What error do you get when hiding the `div`?

Comment: if you use id in a component for an Element. You cannot use that component more then one. If your have same id element more then once you will always get the first one via using document.getElementById('foo')

`<div id="foo">A </div>
  <div id="foo">B</div>`

You cannot get second div never in any component while first component is alive.

Use ViewChild https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild