# Angular 5+: Child Component Subscribed to Parent Observable Does Not Get Value On Unhide

Tags: javascript, angular, event-handling, observable, lifecycle

**EDIT 2**: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37355997/100534) appears to be my general problem, and solution (using `setTimeout` so Angular's lifecycle can happen). I'll either close this or post an answer to my own question when I can.

See **EDIT** for a simpler repro that doesn't involve Subjects/Observables but is essentially the same problem.

I have a parent component that's responsible for fetching data from a service.

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  public mySubject: Subject<Foo[]> = new Subject<Foo[]>();
  public buttonClicked = false;
  private currentValues: Foo[] = null;

  constructor(private SomeService myService) { }

  this.myService.get().subscribe(values => {
    this.mySubject.next(values); // Does NOT work when a child component is hidden, as expected.
    this.currentValues = values; // Keep value so we can manually fire later.
  });

  private buttonClickHandler() {
    this.buttonClicked = true;
    this.mySubject.next(this.currentValues);
  }
}
```

This data is subscribed to in the HTML by a child component. This component is **hidden by default** via `*ngIf`, and only becomes visible on a button click:

`<app-child-component [values]="mySubject.asObservable()" *ngif="buttonClicked" />`

In the parent component above you see I'm trying to pass the current available data to the child by invoking `next()` when the component is made visible in some way:

`this.mySubject.next(this.currentValues);`

**This does not work when initially un-hiding the component via `*ngIf`**. If I click the button a second time, which then calls `next()` again, then it works as expected. But when Angular is in the current context of un-hiding something, observables aren't getting their data. (This also happens when things are unhidden by other means, but the result is the same: If in the same method, the subject/data passing does not work; the component has to already be visible as of the method call.)

I'm guessing the binding to the observable is not happening until after `*ngIf` shows the child component, after the method call resolves. Is there some place I can hook into that I can then pass child data down?

**EDIT for clarification**: I don't believe this is an issue of `Subject` vs. `BehaviorSubject`. I'm not having issue passing the data. The issue is that the data-passing (confirmed via `console.log()`) is not occurring at all in the first place. It's not that the child component is receiving a `null` value. The subscription just isn't firing to the child.

I found I can reproduce this in a simpler fashion too: Trying to select an element in the DOM of `*ngIf` HTML reveals undefined if I make `*ngIf`'s value true within the same Angular method.

```
<div *ngIf="buttonClicked">
  <div id="someElement">Foo</div>
</div>
```

```
public someMethod(): void {
  this.buttonClicked = true;
  const container = document.getElementById('someElement'); // DOES NOT WORK if this.buttonClicked was false at the start of this method!
}
```

Comment: Any chance you could replicate this on https://codesandbox.io/s/angular?

Answer (score 0):

You going to need to use a `BehaviourSubject` instead of Subject, which emits the previously set value initially.

[What is the difference between Subject and BehaviorSubject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43348463/what-is-the-difference-between-subject-and-behaviorsubject)

Comment: I don't think this is a solution to my problem. I'm not having issue holding onto a current value (I can refactor my code later to use `BehaviorSubject` instead of holding onto the value manually). My issue is that the emission is not happening at all to a component who was just un-hidden. I don't think `BehaviorSubject` would fix that? Could be wrong.